# Async promises inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I know this is a topic where there is a lot of info, but I still can't solve this.

I am working with NodeJs that connects to a mysql server, I have an array, I need to iterate the array and do some stuff with the data, the thing is I need to do a query to the mysql server but I need to the for loop wait until I got the results of the query, I have tried a lot of things, now I am trying with .each method of bluebird but still is not working properly, this is my code.

the initial function is Notification.getByUser

thanks in advance

```js
'use strict';
var Promise = require("bluebird");

module.exports = function(Notifications) {
  Notifications.execute = function(sql, itemId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.dataSource.connector.execute(sql, (e, result) => {
        console.log('-----RESULT----', itemId);
        console.log(result);
        console.log('-----ERROR-----', itemId);
        console.log(e);
        if (result.length === 0) {
          resolve(false);
        } else {
          resolve(true);
        }
      });
    });
  };
  Notifications.isMatching = function(item, user, type) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(type, item, user);
      if (item !== null) {
        if (item !== user) {
          resolve(false);
        }
      }

      resolve(true);
    });
  };
  Notifications.getByUser = function(userId, isZolver, countryId, cityId, userState, cb) {
    var where = { status: 1 };
    var plainText = '';
    var items = Notifications.find({ where });
    Promise.each(items, item => {
      return Notifications.isMatching(item.isZolver, isZolver, 'isZolver')
        .then(() => {
          Notifications.isMatching(item.cityId, cityId, 'cityId');
        })
          .then(() => {
            if(item.extraCondition !== null && item.extraCondition !== '') {
              var sql = item.extraCondition.replace(/:user_id/g, userId);
              // console.log(sql);
              Notifications.execute(sql, item.id)
                .then(render => console.log('extraCondition', render));
            } else {
              console.log('extraCondition', true);
            }
          });
    }).then(res => {
      // console.log('res del loop', res);
    });
    cb(null, 'ok');
  };
};
```

Comment: Your `.then` calls have to return something (`return Notifications.execute(sql`, `return Notifications.isMatching`...). And your `isMatching` function is not asynchronous, maybe you can simplify your code

Comment: There is so much wrong with this code: you should probably first tackle a more simple algorithm, learning to work with promises (and not mixing them with a synchronous callback at the end, which just makes the use of promises ... completely useless)

Comment: You can run your code in synchronous manner via nsynjs, please see https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs/tree/master/examples/node-mysql for example of sequential statement execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- In order to chain promises, you must make sure to return promises that you create within a `then` callback
- You should not need to create a promise for results that are immediately available (`isMatching`)
- The `then` callback is always executed when a promise fulfils. It does not matter whether you do `resolve(false)`: even if the promised value is `false` this will still make the promise fulfilled and trigger the `then` callback(s).

There are some unknowns in your code, like `Notifications.find`, and what kind of SQL you are executing: does it return a result set, if so, would you not be interested to get that result instead of just resolving to a boolean?

Anyway, here are some applied corrections:

```
'use strict';
var Promise = require("bluebird");

module.exports = function(Notifications) {
    Notifications.execute = function(sql, itemId) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.dataSource.connector.execute(sql, (e, result) => {
                console.log('-----RESULT----', itemId);
                console.log(result);
                console.log('-----ERROR-----', itemId);
                console.log(e);
                resolve (result.length !== 0); // The `if ... else` is overkill
            });
        });
    };

    //You don't need isMatching to return a promise
    Notifications.isMatching = function(a, b) {
        return a === null || a === b;
    };

    Notifications.getByUser = function(userId, isZolver, countryId, cityId, userState) {
        var where = { status: 1 };
        var items = Notifications.find({ where })
            // use filter() to limit the items to those you want to execute the SQL for
            .filter(item => {
                return Notifications.isMatching(item.isZolver, isZolver)
                    && Notifications.isMatching(item.cityId, cityId)
                    && item.extraCondition !== ''
            });
        // Return the promise! (don't go back to the old callback system!)
        return Promise.each(items, item => {
            var sql = item.extraCondition.replace(/:user_id/g, userId);
            // Return the promise!
            return Notifications.execute(sql, item.id);
        }).then(res => {
            console.log('res del loop', res);
        });
    };
};
```

Note that the signature of `Notifications.getByUser` does not have the final callback parameter: you should keep using promises once you start with them, so when you call this function, call the result's `then` method like you would do for any promise:

```
 Notifications.getByUser( .......arguments....).then( function () {
     // do something...
 });
```

Comment: your answer was awesome, thank you very much, I am a deserter from PHP and javascript sometimes is kinda complicated but incredibly interesting, it's a whole new world to me :)